# Do I need to do some special setting for Virtual Legacy Wire in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In my x86 main board, I connect some special interrupt sources (including NMI) to the south bridge chip. In the datasheet of the chip, it says that these interrupts are sent to CPU via virtual legacy wire (VLW). I don't know VLW well, and I don't know whether it is transparent for software developers.
Currently I can't capture the interrupts in Linux kernel. So my question is that do I need to do some special settings for VLW in kernel? In my previous hardware and code, I used IOAPIC to handle the similar interrupts and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It is transparent to OS and requires no special handling.